# Two statements in one code (choosing by PROMT variable

Tags: sas

I have to different statements in one code. For example:
First:

```
data step2;
set ste1;run;
proc print data=step2;quit;
```

Second:

```
data step6;
set ste5;run;
proc print data=step5;quit;
```

Is it possible to choose by PROMPT variable which one of them I need to Execute?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "PROMT variable", but within a macro you could easily build  something, so only the part you want will be executed depending on a macrovariable..

Comment: How are you running this? Is this an Enterprise Guide project?  Stored Process?  Base SAS program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean a stored process prompt variable, you can simply build a macro:

```
%macro choose;

%if &mypromptvar=1 %then %do;
  data step2;
  set ste1;run;
  proc print data=step2;quit;
%end;

%if &mypromptvar=2 %then %do;
  data step6;
  set ste5;run;
  proc print data=step5;quit;
%end;

%mend;

%choose;
```

where mypromptvar is the name of your promptvariable...

Comment: Unfortunatelly not worting my promt variable = Type (set numeric, 1)
%if  &type=1 %then %do

Comment: @bobby1232: Sorry, but i still dont understand what your "promt variable" means. So if this is not a stored process prompt variable, what is it then? What do you mean by "= Type"? Can you explain a bit more? What is not working?

Comment: its stored process variable

Comment: @bobby1232:OK, then my code above should work, did it several times this way, is there an error message or is it just doing nothing or is there another problem?

Comment: I am testing in Enterprise guide so I just write %let type=1; Is it ok?

Comment: You dont need to write %let type... Sas automatically generates your prompt variable as a macro variable, you just need to access it by its name. I would do some debug steps now to see where the problem is. Maybe an data x; x=&type;run; proc print data=x; run; outside of macro,to see if the variable is recognized and has correct value, or an else statement in macro which randomly prints some data...

Comment: @bobby1232: ok, thats fine, but now i want to know what the problem was? A typo or a wrong name or something else? ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113610/discussion-between-bobby1232-and-kl78).

Comment: my fault, I loose ";" after name macro